# Jquery post method and redirect after success

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, bootstrapvalidator

I am trying to make a post method using jquery. I am using it in a form and with bootstravalidator to validate it. After successful validation, the form gets posted and the php gets in action. Now I am trying to make a redirection to another page after successful post. Here is the code:

```
$('#buy').click(function() {
$.post('php/text.php', $('form#order').serialize(), function () {window.location.href = "index.html";});
});
```

I tried several attempts, but can't get the `window.location.href = "index.html";` correctly. Either the form gets redirected even with faulty validation, or nothing happens at all....

I find it strange, because `'php/text.php', $('form#order').serialize()'` gets only in action if the validation is correct...

**EDIT:**

I am also using bootstrapvalidator to validate the form. THe validation works perfectly and the post method gets executed if everything is okey.

**Bootstrapvalidator:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var validator = $('#order').bootstrapValidator({
            fields: {
                email : {
                    message : "write email adress", 
                    validators : {
                        notEmpty : {
                            message : "Show Email adress"
                        },
                        stringLength : {
                            min : 6,
                            max: 35,
                        }
                    }
                },
            }
        });
      });
```

**EDIT2:**

**HTML:**

```
<form id="order">
  <input type="text" name="name"/><br>
  <input type="text" name="email"/><br>
  <textarea name="comment"></textarea><br>
  <button type="submit" name="send" id="buy">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Is it getting as far as the success function?

Comment: The browser is still submitting the form after your code runs.

Add return false; to the handler to prevent that.

Comment: @Bhavin don't quite get your idea. Could you please show me in the code where?

Comment: @PLAYCUBE, add your `html` code.

Comment: @Dekel I edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You form is submitted once you click on the `#buy` button, and even if your javascript code runs, the page will refresh. If you want to disable the submit of the form you can use `$(form).on('submit', function() { return fase; })`.

This is the updated code:

```
$('#order').on('submit', function() {
    $.post('php/text.php',
          $('form#order').serialize(),
          function () {
              window.location.href = "index.html";
          }
    );
    return false;
});
```

## Update

Since you use the bootstrapvalidator you should use the plugin for the submit process as well (the plugin has a `submitHandler` function that you should use)

This is the updated code of the validator:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var validator = $('#order').bootstrapValidator({
        fields: {
            email : {
                message : "write email adress", 
                validators : {
                    notEmpty : {
                    message : "Show Email adress"
                    },
                    stringLength : {
                        min : 6,
                        max: 35,
                    }
                }
            },
        },
        submitHandler: function(validator, form, submitButton) {
            $.post('php/text.php',
                form.serialize(),
                function () {
                    window.location.href = "index.html";
                }
            );
    });
});
```

Comment: do you know by chance how to make the validation as soon as the page with the form loads, so it won't be necessary when someone presses the submit button? My idea is to enable the the submit button as soon as the validation is alright

Comment: I'm not sure about the validation, But I think my answer is right according to your question so you should accept it.

Comment: @PLAYCUBE, according to the docs of the plugin, in order to force validation of the form you can use `$('#order').data('bootstrapValidator').validate();`

Answer (score 0):

I think you got something wrong.

I'm not sure what you mean by "bootstrapvalidator". Bootstrap itself does not provide validation, only visual indication of otherwise validated form elements.

The code you wrote does not do any "validation".

This `$('form#order').serialize()` will serialize your form, and only include "successful" form elements (see https://api.jquery.com/serialize/ and https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2 for the definition of "successfull"). All other form elements will be left out, leading to an empty string if all form elements are not "successful".

Anyways, this string is (unconditionally) fed to the `$.post()` method, so the POST request will always be run. If the POST request is successfull (meaning a status code of 2xx or 304), your success handler with the redirect will be executed.

So, to achieve your goal, you have to do some kind of validation of your form **before** sending the POST request. You can either do that by hand, or use ony of the jquery or bootstrap plugins made for form validation.

Comment: I think you got something wrong. [bootstrapvalidator](https://github.com/nghuuphuoc/bootstrapvalidator) is a validation library that rely on the bootstrap library.

Comment: Sorry, I answered to the original post not including further specification of "bootstrapvalidator". Put that term into google, and you will find more than just one implementation / plugin. You are of course right, that, '#buy' being a submit button, the form will anyways be submitted. That was not obvious in the first version of the question.

Comment: We also need to know which bootstrapvalidator you are using. It's not obvious what it does (or does not).

Comment: I use an older version: [link]http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/#validator-options

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
             var validator = $('#order').bootstrapValidator({
                    fields: {
                        email : {
                            message : "write email adress", 
                            validators : {
                                notEmpty : {
                                    message : "Show Email adress"
                                },
                                stringLength : {
                                    min : 6,
                                    max: 35,
                                }
                            }
                        },
                    }
                }).bootstrapValidator('validate');
              });

        $(#button).click(function() {
             var validator = $('#order').bootstrapValidator({
                    fields: {
                        email : {
                            message : "write email adress", 
                            validators : {
                                notEmpty : {
                                    message : "Show Email adress"
                                },
                                stringLength : {
                                    min : 6,
                                    max: 35,
                                }
                            }
                        },
                    }
                }).bootstrapValidator('validate');
            var isValid = true;
            if($('#order').find('div.has-error').length > 0){
            isValid = false;
            };
            if (isValid == true){
                $.post('php/text.php', $('form#order').serialize());
                $(location).attr('href','success.html');;
            };
          });
       });
```